# Is there a way to configure Azure blob storage to use my domain SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have my application running http. Some content is at mydomain.com and some content is stored in blob storage with a custom domain setup of media.mydomain.com. This is all working perfectly. Now when I start working on SSL support, I get warnings that I requested content from media.mydomain.com but received content from (standard blob storage url). I've read through the tutorials and guides and none of them seem to touch on SSL.

Is there a configuration in the container somewhere to install my certificate? Or am I forced to load SSL content from the standard content URL instead of my custom domain?

Comment: According to this HTTPS is supported https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/blob-storage/  Old article on adding certificate http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/12/01/how-to-add-an-https-endpoint-to-a-windows-azure-cloud-service.aspx

Comment: HTTPS does work, but if you have setup a CNAME to point your domain or sub-domain to blob storage most browsers warn you that the content has been redirected and is coming from another source. No one wants to alarm customers unnecessarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Azure Blob storage does support HTTPs endpoint so blobs can be accessed over HTTPS however you can not add your own or 3rd party SSL certificate to your Windows Azure Blob Storage endpoint.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. So my app at mydomain.com will have to load some items from myapp.blob.core.windows.net. Not the cleanest look if anyone is paying attention. Is there plans to get a custom certificate loaded in the future?

Comment: Thanks!! This sure is an ask however I am unable to quote anything about future plans. You too can go ahead aand add your feedback here as well: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting

Comment: Is this still the case?